# DFA minimization algorithm understanding

Tags: finite-automata, state-machine, dfa, deterministic

I'm trying to understand this algorithm the DFA minimization algorithm at http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2009/cmsc330/lectures/discussion2.pdf  where it says:

```
while until there is no change in the table contents:
    For each pair of states (p,q) and each character a in the alphabet:
        if Distinct(p,q) is empty and Distinct(δ(p,a), δ(q,a)) is not empty:
            set distinct(p,q) to be x
```

The bit I don't understand is "Distinct(δ(p,a), δ(q,a))" I think I understand the transition function where δ(p,a) = whatever state is reached from p with input a. but with the following DFA:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/arZ8O.png

resulting in this table:

imgur.com/Vg38ZDN.png

shouldn't (c,b) also be marked as an x since distinct(δ(b,0), δ(c,0)) is not empty (d) ?

Answer (score 0):

Distinct(δ(p,a), δ(q,a)) will only be non-empty if δ(p,a) and δ(q,a) are distinct.  In your example, δ(b,0) and δ(c,0) are both d.  Distinct(d, d) is empty since it doesn't make sense for d to be distinct with itself.  Since Distinct(d, d) is empty, we don't mark Distinct(c, b).

In general, Distinct(p, p) where p is a state will always be empty.  Better yet, we don't consider it because it doesn't make sense.